# Cardinality restrictions of topological spaces

Tags: general-topology

For every natural number $n \geq 2$, is there a set $X$ and a topology $T$ on $X$ such that $T$ has cardinality $n$? Or are there forbidden cardinalities? What exactly is the subset of $\mathbb{N}$ which contain precisely those natural numbers which can be cardinalities of finite topologies?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For $n\in\Bbb Z^+$ let $U_n=\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$, and let $$\tau_n=\{\varnothing\}\cup\{U_k:k\le n\}\;$$ then $\tau_n$ is a $T_0$ topology on $U_n$ with $n+1$ members.

A finite $T_1$ topology on a set $X$, however, must have cardinality a power of $2$: each singleton is closed, so $X$ must be finite, and then every subset of $X$ is closed, so every subset of $X$ is open.